# Coontaining Nested Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, nested-loops

I am using WordPress and attempting to nest loops. In the parent loop I want to display regular post and every 3rd post inject a post from the inner loop. The problem is as long as the parent loop has posts then the child loop will spit out its post again which is causing duplicates. Is there a way to only display one post of the child loop at a time and to only show post `while` it `has_posts`?

Comment: Easy solution, don't nest loops. Make two different queries and a counter, loop the first query and when `i%3==0` add one from second query.

Comment: Thanks how would this look in the simplest form?

Comment: Check my answer, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution, don't nest loops. Make two different queries and a counter, loop the first query and when `i%3==0` add one from second query. See if this helps:

```
$apples = get_posts('post_type=apple');
$oranges = get_posts('post_type=orange');

for ($i=0; i<count($apples); $i++) {
  $apple = $apples[$i];
  // do something with $apple  

  // every 3rd apple
  if ($i%3 === 0) {
    $orange = array_shift($oranges);
    // do something with $orange
  }
}
```

At some point you'd have to check if there are enough oranges or not enough apples to print all oranges.

Check docs on [get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) for more info on how to use it.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I almost got it working but ran into an issue. If I try to display the post using something like `the_title()` it loops through the same title of the first post but if I used something like `echo $apple->post_title;` then it loops the all posts correctly. I need to grab the permalink and cannot access the permalink using the object. Is there a reason I cannot use `the_permalink()`? Why does it not cycle through the posts?